# "Hide" options for the lines in the table

Tags: toggle

We have a data table with rows. All these rows can be opened on a new page. Also, users can hide some rows if they do not want to use them.

Now, this "Hide" feature toggles between different states.

We have the following flow: User opens the page -- > looks at the rows -- > finds one (or more) he does not want to use anymore -- > clicks on the toggle --> this row disappears.

If a user wants to go back, he clicks the "Show inactive" button, and the hidden lines appear with "Toggle off".

I do not think Toggle is the best way in this case. But what solution would be better? Maybe checkboxes with the hide button? But if that's the case, it's another step for the user.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar situation but with columns that can be easily applied to rows in [*this StackOverflow answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410553/5765312).

> A clickable toggle on each column that indicates the ability to hide the column, and then a way to restore previously hidden columns.

[image]